# Getting "The server connection has timed out" error while integrating Worklight with WCS

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am following this WebSphere Commerce guide for Worklight store fronts link http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.commerce.starterstores.doc/concepts/csmmobileappworklight.htm, to use Hybrid applications using IBM Worklight 5.0.6.1

The application launches successfully, however when I am trying to place an order I am able to proceed to few steps but then I am getting "The server connection has timed out" error. When I am re-installing the application and again trying to proceed I am getting this error at the different step to place the order.

Can anyone please tell me what could be the problem ?

Logcat Log-

```
                       10-08 14:44:34.504: D/dalvikvm(960): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 448K, 12% free 3852K/4356K, paused 31ms, total 52ms
                       10-08 14:44:45.023: D/Cordova(960): onPageFinished(https://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/m20OrderShippingAddressSelection?langId=-1&catalogId=10351&storeId=11001&krypto=ozwcp04oZRH8ZNEpQt1uBCOuYdwk44PpgfTTecCgo0mHCU82e8AE4c9ZBtspOjBeGDOO%2FOs6E3S2%0D%0AqdiQK1VIal3u9cdnzowkiwqEUH86Ch2G0GJUNWWbPoueoMp8Kurnpy603NCDkCVPqLBUP7v%2F%2FyJD%0D%0AD5Km9vKoCYkAbikFUF9Xp2Xq5ePlMUT1nDj2CpJgeuqQ0B22fI4%3D&ddkey=https:OrderChangeServiceShipInfoUpdate)
                       10-08 14:44:45.033: D/DroidGap(960): onMessage(onNativeReady,null)
                       10-08 14:44:45.033: D/DroidGap(960): onMessage(onPageFinished,https://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/m20OrderShippingAddressSelection?langId=-1&catalogId=10351&storeId=11001&krypto=ozwcp04oZRH8ZNEpQt1uBCOuYdwk44PpgfTTecCgo0mHCU82e8AE4c9ZBtspOjBeGDOO%2FOs6E3S2%0D%0AqdiQK1VIal3u9cdnzowkiwqEUH86Ch2G0GJUNWWbPoueoMp8Kurnpy603NCDkCVPqLBUP7v%2F%2FyJD%0D%0AD5Km9vKoCYkAbikFUF9Xp2Xq5ePlMUT1nDj2CpJgeuqQ0B22fI4%3D&ddkey=https:OrderChangeServiceShipInfoUpdate)
                       10-08 14:44:45.404: D/CordovaNetworkManager(960): Connection Type: 3g
                       10-08 14:44:45.423: D/DroidGap(960): onMessage(spinner,stop)
                       10-08 14:44:45.433: D/WCHybrid(960): initOptionsApp.onDeviceReady ENTRY
                       10-08 14:44:45.443: I/App(960): WARNING: Back Button Default Behaviour will be overridden.  The backbutton event will be fired!
                       10-08 14:44:45.443: D/WCHybrid(960): initOptionsApp.onDeviceReady EXIT
                       10-08 14:44:45.454: D/WCHybrid(960): ondeviceready event dispatched
                       10-08 14:44:45.483: D/WCHybrid(960): wlclient init started
                       10-08 14:44:45.483: D/WCHybrid(960): Read cookies: null
                       10-08 14:44:45.493: D/WCHybrid(960): CookieMgr read cookies: {}
                       10-08 14:44:45.533: D/WCHybrid(960): before: app init onSuccess
                       10-08 14:44:45.543: D/WCHybrid(960): WCHybridAppJS.wlEnvInit ENTRY
                       10-08 14:44:45.543: D/WCHybrid(960): WCHybridAppJS.wlCommonInit ENTRY
                       10-08 14:44:45.543: D/WCHybrid(960): WCHybridAppJS.wlCommonInit langId(string): -1
                       10-08 14:44:45.553: D/WCHybrid(960): WCHybridAppJS.wlCommonInit langId(number): -1
                       10-08 14:44:45.553: D/WCHybrid(960): MessagesJS.setLanguage lang ID used: -1
                       10-08 14:44:45.573: D/WCHybrid(960): WCHybridAppJS.wlCommonInit EXIT
                       10-08 14:44:45.573: D/WCHybrid(960): WCHybridAppJS.wlEnvInit android environment initializing started
                       10-08 14:44:45.583: D/WCHybrid(960): WCHybridAppJS.updateTabState ENTRY
                       10-08 14:44:45.583: D/WCHybrid(960): WCHybridAppJS.getCurrentTabIndex ENTRY
                       10-08 14:44:45.583: D/WCHybrid(960): WCHybridAppJS.getCurrentTabIndex selectedTab=3
                       10-08 14:44:45.593: D/WCHybrid(960): WCHybridAppJS.getCurrentTabIndex EXIT
                       10-08 14:44:45.593: D/WCHybrid(960): WCHybridAppJS.updateTabState EXIT
                       10-08 14:44:45.593: D/WCHybrid(960): WCHybridAppJS.createOptionsMenu ENTRY
                       10-08 14:44:45.633: D/WCHybrid(960): WCHybridAppJS.createOptionsMenu EXIT
                       10-08 14:44:45.633: D/WCHybrid(960): WCHybridAppJS.wlEnvInit android environment initialization completed
                       10-08 14:44:45.633: D/WCHybrid(960): WCHybridAppJS.wlEnvInit EXIT
                       10-08 14:44:45.633: D/WCHybrid(960): after: app init onSuccess
                       10-08 14:44:45.643: D/WCHybrid(960): wlclient init success
                       10-08 14:44:48.834: D/Cordova(960): onPageFinished(https://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/m20OrderShippingAddressSelection?langId=-1&catalogId=10351&storeId=11001&krypto=ozwcp04oZRH8ZNEpQt1uBCOuYdwk44PpgfTTecCgo0mHCU82e8AE4c9ZBtspOjBeGDOO%2FOs6E3S2%0D%0AqdiQK1VIal3u9cdnzowkiwqEUH86Ch2G0GJUNWWbPoueoMp8Kurnpy603NCDkCVPqLBUP7v%2F%2FyJD%0D%0AD5Km9vKoCYkAbikFUF9Xp2Xq5ePlMUT1nDj2CpJgeuqQ0B22fI4%3D&ddkey=https:OrderChangeServiceShipInfoUpdate#)
                       10-08 14:44:48.844: D/DroidGap(960): onMessage(onNativeReady,null)
                       10-08 14:44:48.844: D/DroidGap(960): onMessage(onPageFinished,https://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/m20OrderShippingAddressSelection?langId=-1&catalogId=10351&storeId=11001&krypto=ozwcp04oZRH8ZNEpQt1uBCOuYdwk44PpgfTTecCgo0mHCU82e8AE4c9ZBtspOjBeGDOO%2FOs6E3S2%0D%0AqdiQK1VIal3u9cdnzowkiwqEUH86Ch2G0GJUNWWbPoueoMp8Kurnpy603NCDkCVPqLBUP7v%2F%2FyJD%0D%0AD5Km9vKoCYkAbikFUF9Xp2Xq5ePlMUT1nDj2CpJgeuqQ0B22fI4%3D&ddkey=https:OrderChangeServiceShipInfoUpdate#)
                       10-08 14:44:48.924: D/DroidGap(960): onMessage(onPageStarted,https://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/OrderChangeServiceShipInfoUpdate)
                       10-08 14:44:49.384: I/Choreographer(960): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
                       10-08 14:45:01.733: D/CordovaWebView(960): >>> loadUrl(https://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/m20OrderBillingAddressSelection?catalogId=10351&langId=-1&storeId=11001&krypto=FA39HZHxK1PiugIAR%2FmherjelN1e%2FgduRyYr%2FYW46jMU2FMxE0C8GSxsGzUk78Bv&ddkey=https:OrderChangeServiceShipInfoUpdate)
                       10-08 14:45:01.733: D/CordovaWebView(960): >>> loadUrlNow()
                       10-08 14:45:01.783: D/Cordova(960): onPageFinished(https://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/m20OrderBillingAddressSelection?catalogId=10351&langId=-1&storeId=11001&krypto=FA39HZHxK1PiugIAR%2FmherjelN1e%2FgduRyYr%2FYW46jMU2FMxE0C8GSxsGzUk78Bv&ddkey=https:OrderChangeServiceShipInfoUpdate)
                       10-08 14:45:01.783: D/DroidGap(960): onMessage(onNativeReady,null)
                       10-08 14:45:01.783: D/DroidGap(960): onMessage(onPageFinished,https://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/m20OrderBillingAddressSelection?catalogId=10351&langId=-1&storeId=11001&krypto=FA39HZHxK1PiugIAR%2FmherjelN1e%2FgduRyYr%2FYW46jMU2FMxE0C8GSxsGzUk78Bv&ddkey=https:OrderChangeServiceShipInfoUpdate)
                       10-08 14:45:01.783: D/DroidGap(960): onMessage(onPageStarted,https://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/m20OrderBillingAddressSelection?catalogId=10351&langId=-1&storeId=11001&krypto=FA39HZHxK1PiugIAR%2FmherjelN1e%2FgduRyYr%2FYW46jMU2FMxE0C8GSxsGzUk78Bv&ddkey=https:OrderChangeServiceShipInfoUpdate)
                       10-08 14:45:01.973: D/WCHybrid(960): WCHybridAppJS.updateHistory ENTRY
                       10-08 14:45:01.983: D/WCHybrid(960): WCHybridAppJS.getCurrentTabIndex ENTRY
                       10-08 14:45:01.983: D/WCHybrid(960): WCHybridAppJS.getCurrentTabIndex selectedTab=3
                       10-08 14:45:01.983: D/WCHybrid(960): WCHybridAppJS.getCurrentTabIndex EXIT
                       10-08 14:45:01.983: D/WCHybrid(960): WCHybridAppJS.updateHistory Updated contents of historyStack_3
                       10-08 14:45:01.983: D/WCHybrid(960): WCHybridAppJS.updateHistory URL[0]: http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/m20OrderItemDisplay?catalogId=10351&langId=-1&storeId=11001
                       10-08 14:45:01.993: D/WCHybrid(960): WCHybridAppJS.updateHistory EXIT
```

Sever Log-

```
                       [10/8/13 14:38:44:985 IST] 00000030 SolrCore      I org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute [MC_10351_CatalogGroup_en_US] webapp=null path=/select params={debugQuery=false&fl=catgroup_id%2CparentCatgroup_id_facet%2Cidentifier_ntk%2Cname%2CshortDescription%2Cthumbnail%2Cprice_USD%2Cstoreent_id&start=0&rows=50&timeAllowed=15000&facet=true&q=%2B%28%28*%3A*%29+AND+%28identifier_ntk%3A%28%22Appliances%22%29%29%29+%28_val_%3A%22product%28-0.001%2CgetSequenceByCatalogAndCategory%28sequence%2C%2710351%27%2C%27-1%27%29%29%22%29&fq=storeent_id%3A%28%2211001%22%29&fq=published%3A1&fq=catalog_id%3A10351} hits=1 status=0 QTime=31 
                       [10/8/13 14:38:46:124 IST] 00000030 SolrCore      I org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute [MC_10351_CatalogEntry_en_US] webapp=null path=/select params={debugQuery=false&fl=catentry_id%2Cprice_USD%2Cstoreent_id&start=0&rows=1&timeAllowed=15000&facet=true&facet.sort=count&facet.mincount=1&facet.limit=-1&facet.query=parentCatgroup_id_search%3A10351_10347&q=*%3A*&fq=catalog_id%3A%2210351%22&fq=storeent_id%3A%28%2211001%22%29&fq=published%3A1} hits=3162 status=0 QTime=0 
                       [10/8/13 14:38:46:997 IST] 00000030 SolrCore      I org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute [MC_10351_CatalogEntry_en_US] webapp=null path=/select params={debugQuery=false&start=0&rows=20&timeAllowed=15000&facet=true&facet.field=parentCatgroup_id_search&facet.field=price_USD&facet.field=mfName_ntk_cs&f.parentCatgroup_id_search.facet.limit=21&f.parentCatgroup_id_search.facet.mincount=1&f.parentCatgroup_id_search.facet.sort=count&facet.query=price_USD%3A%28%7B*+100%7D+100%29&facet.query=price_USD%3A%28%7B100+200%7D+200%29&facet.query=price_USD%3A%28%7B200+300%7D+300%29&facet.query=price_USD%3A%28%7B300+400%7D+400%29&facet.query=price_USD%3A%28%7B400+500%7D+500%29&facet.query=price_USD%3A%28%7B500+*%7D%29&f.price_USD.facet.limit=21&f.price_USD.facet.mincount=1&f.price_USD.facet.sort=count&f.mfName_ntk_cs.facet.limit=21&f.mfName_ntk_cs.facet.mincount=1&f.mfName_ntk_cs.facet.sort=count&q=%2B%28*%3A*%29+%28_val_%3A%22product%28-0.001%2CgetSequenceByCatalogAndCategory%28sequence%2C%2710351%27%2C%2710347%27%29%29%22%29&fq=catalog_id%3A%2210351%22&fq=parentCatgroup_id_search%3A%2210351_10347%22&fq=storeent_id%3A%28%2211001%22%29&fq=published%3A1&fq=-%28catenttype_id_ntk_cs%3AItemBean+AND+parentCatentry_id%3A%5B*+TO+*%5D%29} hits=44 status=0 QTime=0 
                       [10/8/13 14:39:19:833 IST] 00000034 SolrCore      I org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute [MC_10351_CatalogEntry_en_US] webapp=null path=/select params={debugQuery=false&fl=catentry_id%2Cstoreent_id%2Cbuyable%2CpartNumber_ntk%2Cname%2Cthumbnail%2CfullImage%2CshortDescription%2ClongDescription%2Ckeyword%2CmfName_ntk%2Ccatenttype_id_ntk_cs%2CparentCatgroup_id_facet%2CparentCatentry_id%2CsubscripType%2CdisallowRecOrder%2Cprice_USD&start=0&rows=1&timeAllowed=15000&facet=true&q=%28*%3A*%29+AND+%28catentry_id%3A%28%2214842%22%29%29&fq=storeent_id%3A%28%2211001%22%29&fq=published%3A1} hits=1 status=0 QTime=0 
                       [10/8/13 14:39:20:026 IST] 00000034 SolrCore      I org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute [MC_10351_CatalogEntry_en_US] webapp=null path=/select params={debugQuery=false&fl=catentry_id%2CparentCatentry_id%2Cbuyable%2Cthumbnail%2Cprice_USD%2Cstoreent_id&start=0&rows=200&timeAllowed=15000&facet=true&q=parentCatentry_id%3A14842&fq=storeent_id%3A%28%2211001%22%29&fq=published%3A1} hits=1 status=0 QTime=0 
                       [10/8/13 14:39:20:816 IST] 00000034 SolrCore      I org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute [MC_10351_CatalogEntry_Unstructured_en_US] webapp=null path=/select params={debugQuery=false&fl=attachment_id%2Ccatentry_id%2Cpath%2Cname%2Cmimetype%2Crulename%2Cidentifier%2Cimage%2Cshortdesc%2Clongdesc%2Ctika_stream_size%2Cprice_USD%2Cstoreent_id&start=0&rows=20&timeAllowed=15000&facet=true&q=catentry_id%3A14842} hits=0 status=0 QTime=0 
                       [10/8/13 14:39:21:426 IST] 00000034 SolrCore      I org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute [MC_10351_CatalogEntry_en_US] webapp=null path=/select params={debugQuery=false&fl=catentry_id%2Cprice_USD%2Cstoreent_id&start=0&rows=5000&timeAllowed=15000&facet=true&q=catentry_id%3A%2214843%22&fq=storeent_id%3A%28%2211001%22%29&fq=published%3A1} hits=1 status=0 QTime=0 
                       [10/8/13 14:39:21:726 IST] 00000034 SolrCore      I org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute [MC_10351_CatalogEntry_en_US] webapp=null path=/select params={debugQuery=false&fl=catentry_id%2Cprice_USD%2Cstoreent_id&start=0&rows=5000&timeAllowed=15000&facet=true&q=catentry_id%3A%2214842%22&fq=storeent_id%3A%28%2211001%22%29&fq=published%3A1} hits=1 status=0 QTime=0 
                       [10/8/13 14:39:21:726 IST] 00000034 SolrCore      I org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute [MC_10351_CatalogEntry_en_US] webapp=null path=/select params={debugQuery=false&fl=catentry_id%2Cprice_USD%2Cstoreent_id&start=0&rows=5000&timeAllowed=15000&facet=true&q=catentry_id%3A%2214842%22&fq=storeent_id%3A%28%2211001%22%29&fq=published%3A1} hits=1 status=0 QTime=0 
                       [10/8/13 14:39:21:736 IST] 00000034 SolrCore      I org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute [MC_10351_CatalogEntry_en_US] webapp=null path=/select params={debugQuery=false&fl=catentry_id%2Cstoreent_id%2Cbuyable%2CpartNumber_ntk%2Cname%2Cthumbnail%2CfullImage%2CshortDescription%2ClongDescription%2Ckeyword%2CmfName_ntk%2Ccatenttype_id_ntk_cs%2CparentCatgroup_id_facet%2CparentCatentry_id%2CsubscripType%2CdisallowRecOrder%2Cprice_USD&start=0&rows=1&timeAllowed=15000&facet=true&q=%28*%3A*%29+AND+%28catentry_id%3A%28%2214842%22%29%29&fq=storeent_id%3A%28%2211001%22%29&fq=published%3A1} hits=1 status=0 QTime=0 
                       [10/8/13 14:39:21:746 IST] 00000034 SolrCore      I org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute [MC_10351_CatalogEntry_en_US] webapp=null path=/select params={debugQuery=false&fl=catentry_id%2CparentCatentry_id%2Cbuyable%2Cthumbnail%2Cprice_USD%2Cstoreent_id&start=0&rows=200&timeAllowed=15000&facet=true&q=parentCatentry_id%3A14842&fq=storeent_id%3A%28%2211001%22%29&fq=published%3A1} hits=1 status=0 QTime=0 
                       [10/8/13 14:40:01:536 IST] 00000034 SolrCore      I org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute [MC_10351_CatalogEntry_en_US] webapp=null path=/select params={debugQuery=false&fl=catentry_id%2Cprice_USD%2Cstoreent_id&start=0&rows=5000&timeAllowed=15000&facet=true&q=catentry_id%3A%2214843%22&fq=storeent_id%3A%28%2211001%22%29&fq=published%3A1} hits=1 status=0 QTime=0 
                       [10/8/13 14:40:01:677 IST] 00000034 SolrCore      I org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute [MC_10351_CatalogEntry_en_US] webapp=null path=/select params={debugQuery=false&fl=catentry_id%2Cprice_USD%2Cstoreent_id&start=0&rows=5000&timeAllowed=15000&facet=true&q=catentry_id%3A%2214843%22&fq=storeent_id%3A%28%2211001%22%29&fq=published%3A1} hits=1 status=0 QTime=0 
                       [10/8/13 14:43:42:064 IST] 00000073 SolrCore      I org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute [MC_10351_CatalogEntry_en_US] webapp=null path=/select params={debugQuery=false&fl=catentry_id%2Cprice_USD%2Cstoreent_id&start=0&rows=5000&timeAllowed=15000&facet=true&q=catentry_id%3A%2214843%22&fq=storeent_id%3A%28%2211001%22%29&fq=published%3A1} hits=1 status=0 QTime=0 
                       [10/8/13 14:44:14:317 IST] 00000032 SolrCore      I org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute [MC_10351_CatalogEntry_en_US] webapp=null path=/select params={debugQuery=false&fl=catentry_id%2Cprice_USD%2Cstoreent_id&start=0&rows=5000&timeAllowed=15000&facet=true&q=catentry_id%3A%2214843%22&fq=storeent_id%3A%28%2211001%22%29&fq=published%3A1} hits=1 status=0 QTime=0
```

Comment: It would be best if you add logs from your server, from the same time when you get the error, as well any logs from the device (LogCat for Android, Xcode Console for iOS).

Comment: Hi Idan, I have added WCS and logcat logs.

Comment: Hi Idan, any suggestion which I can try ?

Comment: The logs do not show any error, so it is difficult to understand where the problem happens; These forms, they are part of the Worklight app? Try increasing all timout values; consult with the IBM Information Center to find out what are those.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing on an emulator or an actual Android device?

If emulator, which API level (OS level, e.g. 4.1.1 etc.) are you on? Frequently, I have noticed that my emulator will lose internet connection after varying amounts of time. The only workaround I have found so far is to close and restart the emulator.

There are various open threads discussing issues with similar symptoms with the emulator, but no resolution yet:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22403

If possible, try testing on an actual device to see if the issue is reproducible there.

Comment: I am using emulator with OS level 4.3. Yes, you are correct... the only workaround I found is to close and restart the emulator. I have not yet checked on the real device but I will certainly try out this.